# Slider Image getting blured in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am working on a website, some other guys developed it and make a lot of mess that i have to clear. One of the problem is getting very annoying.

I have designed some banners for the slider with the same size of previous banners but when i uploaded them in wordpress and set them they get blurred. Don't know what is the problem

Please check and let me know . Thank You

[View Website](http://mobiespion.com)

Answer (score 1):

You call images processed by **timthumb** which modify the image. For instance, you have one image slider source like this :

```
/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/pose-1024x298.jpg&h=320&w=1100&zc=1
```

If you can change the image source (depending on your slider admin backoffice), just put :

```
/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/pose-1024x298.jpg&h=298&w=1024&zc=1
```

...so you won't have any crop up.

Or you can even try to put the original image source with no paramater :

```
/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/pose-1024x298.jp
```

Comment: ok.. then i have to save the file with timthumb.jpg or png and then upload it from wordpress but there are different slider images.

Can you explain more.

Comment: I don't know how work your slider backend, but what I see is wrong parameters for the images. The image original height is 298px and width is 1024px. Obviously, with the current parameters in the url, you have 320px and 1100px which is more than the original image. So the browser rendering is blured.